# Weird spam / comment combination

Tags: discussion, spam, trolling

I flagged [this post on math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2719293). It got closed quickly after that.

Shortly afterwards, I received this comment on a completely unrelated post. I think the comment is gone, and looking at the only user with that name shows no comments. A picture of the comment is below.

> [image]

The linked post in the comment was the one linked above in my question.

Should I take the commenter's advice, or is it part of the problem? Should I just flag anything like this I see in the future, and not comment?

Comment: This is generally about spam on the network and about someone who posts it all over the place... this is not limited to the Math site alone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need to be alarmed.

There is a chat bot called [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector), which detects spam/offensive posts all over the SE network, and post chat messages with links, letting users flag it quickly.

Most likely SmokeDetector posted a link to the same question you flagged, Makyen followed that link, was able to see your comment before the question was deleted, and wasn't able to reply in time, so he commented on one of your other posts, which is a common way to send a message to someone.

Anyway, he has a good point. Internet trolls feed on attention. Commenting on obvious trolling isn't a good practice, and that's what he referred to as "feeding the troll". Best to just flag/vote to close/delete such trolling posts, without any comment, in the future.